# Will there be a SPA template for asp.net web forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I know `MVC4` will have a `Single Page Application template`. Any information about web forms?

Answer (score 0):

No such template has been introduced yet in the VS11 beta so I would be surprised if Microsoft include one in the RTM. Could be wrong of course.

Answer (score 0):

There is a template called "Hot Towelette SPA" @ http://www.johnpapa.net/spa/ at the bottom of page.

I haven't play with it yet but from its description it says : "Hot Towel also comes as a NuGet package that you can add to an ASP.NET application (no MVC required)"

Don't mix it; Towel is for MVC, and Towelette is for no-MVC.

Hope it helps.